# Как сделать одинаковые отступы с двух сторон на флексах?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
}

.whaper{
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    
}

.main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
}

.header{
    height: 80px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 1280px;
}












.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Это включает позиционирование относительно <form>, */
  /* а не относительно всей страницы */
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {
  width: 188px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  /* Позиционирование относительно <form> */
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px; /* 2px - размер border'а поля формы */
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;

  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;      
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aditii</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
       <div class="whaper">
        <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
            <h1>Aditii</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
            <form action="#" class="search-form">
                  <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="Search.." />
                    <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
                    <!-- Сюда можно запихнуть любую картинку на свой вкус -->
                       <img src="img/Search%201.png" alt="">
                    </button>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="korzina">
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/13/8a7753a627c0f71b8149eb94c44dd162-full.png" alt=""> <h2>$300</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Опиши подробнее что тебе нужно))Про какие отступы каких элементов  вообще идет речь?

Comment: @A.Ivankov Про отступы с лева и с право от границы блока, возле надписи Aditii и корзинки. И что бы эти отступы были одинаковы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вас правильно понял?)))

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.whaper {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 1280px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;/* вот тут отспуп */
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Это включает позиционирование относительно <form>, */
  /* а не относительно всей страницы */
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {
  width: 188px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  /* Позиционирование относительно <form> */
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  /* 2px - размер border'а поля формы */
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Aditii</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="whaper">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>Aditii</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="search">
          <form action="#" class="search-form">
            <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="Search.." />
            <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
                    <!-- Сюда можно запихнуть любую картинку на свой вкус -->
                       <img src="img/Search%201.png" alt="">
                    </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="korzina">
          <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/13/8a7753a627c0f71b8149eb94c44dd162-full.png" alt="">
          <h2>$300</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: да правильно, а с помощью какого тега вы сделали отступы?

Comment: посмотри в коде, я эту строчку которую добавил в твой код прокомментировал

Comment: ага всё понял благодарю

Comment: окей уже  принял

Comment: Стоит добавить пояснение в сам вопрос, комментарии в коде тяжело заметить, когда кода довольно много

Comment: @Grundy Согласен, но все же там не много было, был уверен, что заметит разницу в коде...

Comment: @Air, проблема в том, что на первый взгляд - код абсолютно одинаковый, что в ответе, что в вопросе, и комментарии только со второго экрана начинаются.